# typescript: Unrecognized this in class

Tags: typescript, class, this

typescript version: 3.9.2

The expectation is to declare an interface constraint that allows only non-functional member keys on the class

```js
type NonFunctionKeys<T extends {}> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Function ? never : K
}[keyof T];

class MyClass {
  someKey: boolean = true;
  set<T extends keyof this>(key:T, value: this[T]) {
  }
  setValue<T extends NonFunctionKeys<this>>(key:T, value: this[T]) {
  }
  foo() {
    // is ok
    this.set('someKey', true);
    // is ok
    (this as MyClass).setValue('someKey', true);
    // next line will report error
    // 2345: Argument of type '"childValue"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this[keyof this] extends Function ? never : keyof this'.
    this.setValue('someKey', true);
  }
}

// and that is ok 
const c = new MyClass();
c.set('someKey', true)
c.setValue('someKey', true)
```

Doesn't typescript recognize `this`? However, IDE can give the correct hint, and the type judgment is correct when using attributes

PS: append note, the scenario here is relatively simple, but actually it involves inheritance, the value of the set may be a member of the super class, or if the class is inherited, the subclass will have additional properties, so i can't write a specific MyClass instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is impossible. If you want to call `setValue` from the place where you don't know if the object you have is of base class or derived class until runtime then type system can't know that either. So you should just cover all possible cases with manual runtime checks and casts like so:

```
type NonFunctionKeys<T extends {}> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Function ? never : K
}[keyof T];

class MyClass {
    someKey: boolean = true;
    set<T extends keyof this>(key: T, value: this[T]) {
    }
    setValue<T extends NonFunctionKeys<this>>(key: T, value: this[T]) {
    }
    foo() {
        // is ok
        this.set('someKey', true);
        // is ok
        (this as MyClass).setValue('someKey', true);
        // next line will report error
        // 2345: Argument of type '"childValue"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this[keyof this] extends Function ? never : keyof this'.
        if (this instanceof MyDerivedClass) {
            (this as MyDerivedClass).setValue('otherKey', true);
        } else  if (this instanceof MyClass) {
            (this as MyClass).setValue('someKey', true);
        }
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass extends MyClass {
    otherKey: boolean = false;
}

// and that is ok 
const c = new MyDerivedClass();
c.foo()
```

I'm not entirely sure why manual casts are necessary because I'd expect [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) to kick in. But it's not a huge inconvenience to do a manual cast since you just checked that the object is of the type that you need a cast to.

Comment: I thought the type system should know should know: **this** is instanceof MyDerivedClass extends MyClass, and **this** should be (instanceof MyDerivedClass) & (instnaceof MyClass);  and why does **keyof this** can work good

Comment: That's a good point. I think if you expect the same functionality from your solution as the one you get from just `keyof this` then it should be possible to get it. So probably that's not implemented yet. You might want to file a bug for TypeScript describing how `keyof this` works but when you narrow it down to non-function properties using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) exactly like it's shown in documentation it no longer works for `this`.